# When to use jQuery.ajax and when to use jQuery.post?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

It seems, at the first glass, that we can use either of those. I'm wondering, however, when should we use one or the other, assuming a scenario where we can do the same thing with any of those two.

Thanks in advance,
MEM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) is actually derived from [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). You can use [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) when you want want to set the `POST` method in your request. [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) allows you to set both `GET` and `POST` request methods.

Comment: Thanks a lot four the clarification. It would be nice to share some answers here... oh well...

Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

`jQuery.post` is a shorthand method which calls `jQuery.ajax`.

If you don't need any functionality not supported by the shorthand, you might as well use it.

It's defined like this:

```
post: function( url, data, callback, type ) {
    // shift arguments if data argument was omited
    if ( jQuery.isFunction( data ) ) {
        type = type || callback;
        callback = data;
        data = {};
    }

    return jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success: callback,
        dataType: type
    });
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `$.ajax` allows you to set callbacks for failure, and completion, while `$.post` has callback only for success. Also, `$.ajax` allows to set a callback to be invoked before the sending of the request and set other useful parameters as timeout time , username or password if the target script needs authentication.

In short, `$.post` is a useful shortcut to use in the simpler situation, while `$.ajax` offers full control on the request.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm sure the more I use jquery the more I can get about it. :)